# If someone has the right to something, how could I say in this situation

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrases, expressions

If someone has the right to something, how could I say in this situation.

My client would like an organiser to cover flight ticket fare for business class due to physical health problem. According to the organiser, the reason is acceptable for the fee coverage for business class seat.
I would like to use another word instead of "the reason is acceptable".
Do following phrases make sense for "the reason is acceptable"?

> Your reason is a target to be covered fees by the organiser.
>   Your reason is subject to be covered fees by the organiser.
>   Your reason deserves to be covered fees by the organiser.
>   Your reason was regarded as subject of fee coverage by the organiser.

Reasons for physical health matters are considerable point.

I guess that all of the phrases do not fit in the situation.
Please teach me how do native speakers say in this situation?

Comment: This question is unclear, can you clarify what you are asking. Also see [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) for help with learning English

Comment: Thank you for your post. I add more information into the subject.

Comment: Questions (because your wording is unclear in some places): 1. Has the organiser (i) already agreed to pay the fare, or (ii) only said that it seems acceptable, without making a commitment? 2.Are you writing to (i) your client or (ii) the organiser?  (I think you are indicating 1.(i) & 2.(i), but I want to be sure.

Comment: Many thanks for your kind support. Yes, you guess right. I meant that I am writing to the client for informing the organiser's decision.

Answer (score 2):

Your health condition [entitles](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/entitle) you to the seat upgrade.

M-W:
entitled -ˈtīt-liŋ, -əl-iŋ\
transitive verb

1
:  to give a title to :  designate

**2
:  to furnish with proper grounds for seeking or claiming something**

Comment: This also fits in in the situation. which one "entitles - to -" or " be eligible for" do native speakers usually use in business scene? Thank you for your kind cooperation.

Comment: Absolutely. I've seen the word used throughout employee manuals and memos about employee rights - e.g., "All full-time employees are entitled to x days paid sick time."

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think the answer to your question is **"the client is eligible for an upgrade"** , but let's clarify first, looks like your question is: *"How to suggest your client gets a business class seat due to health impairment"*, is that correct?

**"The client is eligible for an upgrade to a Business Class seat on the grounds of health impairment"**

Now, regarding the *"reason is acceptable"* part:

You may try using **"My client falls under the category of the disabled persons and persons with reduced mobility, therefore he/she has a right to require a seat upgrade according to the regulations of (the company name)"**

I hope this helps.

Comment: Seems that those sentences get to the point! I very much appreciate your kind cooperation and thank you for trying to understand what I wanted to mean. I have been always wondering how do native speakers say this in English every time this situation comes.

Answer (score 0):

You have clarified in your comments that you want to write to the client informing him/her that the organiser has agreed to cover your client's business-class fare for travel to the event.  I would phrase that along the following lines:

> I am pleased to inform you that the organiser has agreed to cover the costs of your [return ?] flight by business class because of your disability/health condition.